# How to set fill color property of custom UIView (a circle) from View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uicolor, cashapelayer

I'm guessing I don't know enough about Quartz or CAShapeLayer manipulations, but I wanted to know how to change the fill color to custom UIView that I have.

Here's the implementation for `DotView`:

```
#define kCustomBlue     [UIColor colorWithRed:181.0/255 green:228.0/255 blue:226.0/255 alpha:1]

@implementation DotView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.opaque = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.opaque = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    [super drawRect:rect];

    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect] CGPath]];
    circleLayer.fillColor = kCustomBlue.CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
} 
@end
```

After placing a `DotView` object (`(nonatomic, weak)` IBOutlet in my `ViewController` interface) in my Storyboard, I run the code and everything is fine and dandy.  That object in my `ViewController` interface is called `dot1`

I want to have a property `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* fillingColor;` which sets the fill color for the view.  How do I implement that correctly?

The idea is this: there is a tap gesture recognizer object attached to the `dot1` view, and everytime I tap the dot, the color changes from blue to black (then black to blue).

I'm using XCode 9.3 and have an iPhone 7 running iOS 11.2

Thanks, Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Add the property to the .h:

```
@interface DotView: UIView

// Add this to everything else you have
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* fillingColor;

@end
```

Then in the .m, override the setter:

```
- (void)setFillingColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _fillingColor = color;

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Then in `drawRect:`, use your `fillingColor` property for the fill color:

```
circleLayer.fillColor = self.fillingColor.CGColor;
```

Please note that you do not want to be adding layers over and over every time `drawRect:` is called. You don't even need to use layers for this. Just fill the `UIBezierPath`.